# How to merge two index of array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

How to merge only index of array itself, I have only one and I want to combine its index, I want to make 3d to 2d array. I just want to combine index of one array with in one index.This is one array,I am not asking for merge two different array.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [East] => 2
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [North] => 2
    )

)
```

Now I want to format this array like below format.there can be nth no of indexes with in same array.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [East] => 2
        [North] => 2
    )

)
```

Comment: this is not duplicate.check there that is for two arrays i m asking single array and within the array.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$a = array(0 => array('East' => 2), 1 => array('North' => 2));

$b[0] = $a[0];

for($i = 1; $i < count($a); $i++) {
  $key = array_keys($a[$i])[0];
  $b[0][$key] = $a[$i][$key];
}   

print_r($b);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [East] => 2
        [North] => 2
    )

)
```